# Storybook 6.x and Vue 2 fails on additional loaders needed

Tags: vue.js, webpack, storybook

Migrating to `Storybook 6.4`

I have a story that is loading a `Vue` component and I keep failing with the following errors:

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (92:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-docgen-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-docgen-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|
|
> .my-card {
```

That `.my-card` appears right after my `<style>` tag in the vue file so I'm suspecting something with regards to typescript, babel or webpack - specifically not using the `vue-loader` to load the SFC

My storybook `main.js` has `framework: "@storybook/vue",`
I've set `webpackFinal` to resolve "@", "css" and "scss"

here is my `.storybook/main.js`:

```
const path = require('path')

  module.exports = {
    stories: [ '../src/**/*.stories.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)' ],
    addons: [
      '@storybook/addon-essentials',
      '@storybook/addon-actions',
      {
        name: '@storybook/addon-docs',
        options: {
          babelOptions: {
            presets: [
              [
                '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
                {
                  jsx: false
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      '@storybook/addon-knobs',
      '@storybook/addon-links',
      '@storybook/addon-notes'
    ],
    webpackFinal: async config => {
      config.resolve.alias = {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, "../src")
      }

      // Sass loader
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                indentedSyntax: true,
              },
              prependData: "@import '@/sass/variables.sass'",
            },
          },
        ],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
      })

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader',
      ]
      })

      return config;
    },
    framework: "@storybook/vue",
    features: { postcss: false }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing Vue typescript loader. adding this to .storybook/main.js helped:

```
webpackFinal: async config => {
config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loader: "ts-loader",
      options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] },
    });
return config;
}
```

also **upgrading** my `vue-loader` to `16.8.2` helped

Answer (score 0):

I had the same `ModuleParseError` due to using SCSS though was not using TypeScript in a particular Storybook 6 / Vue 2 / Webpack 5 project.

I solved it by modifying the `webpackFinal` key of `.storybook/main.js` as [documented](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config):

```
module.exports = {
  // ... other irrelevant config
  // NB: webpackFinal is top level, not nested inside "core"
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  }
}
```

Based on [this source](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/17768#issuecomment-1160352435) first which led to [this](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/17768#issuecomment-1172856879) and so ultimately the main [one that need be read](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config).

I also could have created a `.storybook/webpack.config.js` and put the config in there, as follows.

Note that storybook does not seem to look outside its `.storybook` directory for webpack configurations (like the one at the top level of a project), though it is [possible to reuse or merge them in](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack#using-your-existing-config).

```
module.exports = {
  // ...irrelevant
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/env"],
            plugins: ["@babel/transform-arrow-functions", "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      // ...irrelevant
```

Aside: To help this kind of debugging in future, do:

1. Read the [storybook webpack docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack)
2. Run commands like `yarn storybook --debug-webpack`